# Reading line containing multiple XML tags

Tags: perl, shell

I have a text file containing lines with multiple xml tags in single line.Below is the sample of it (returns and spacing added for clarity).

```
xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" EchoToken="1397133927.05244" TimeStamp="2014-04-10T07:45:27.00-05:00" Target="Production" Version="1.002" PrimaryLangID="en-us"><POS><Source><RequestorID Type="18" ID="HILTON"/></Source></POS><AvailStatusMessages ChainCode="ES" BrandCode="ES" HotelCode="41914">
  <AvailStatusMessage><StatusApplicationControl Start="2014-04-20" End="2014-04-26" Sun="1" InvCodeApplication="InvCode" InvCode="U1K" RatePlanCodeType="RatePlanCode" RatePlanCode="EXL" RateTier="8" IsRoom="1" Override="1"/><LengthsOfStay ArrivalDateBased="1" FixedPatternLength="2"><LengthOfStay Time="1" TimeUnit="Day" MinMaxMessageType="FullPatternLOS"/></LengthsOfStay></AvailStatusMessage>
  <AvailStatusMessage><StatusApplicationControl Start="2014-04-20" End="2014-04-26" Mon="1" Tue="1" Weds="1" Thur="1" Fri="1" Sat="1" InvCodeApplication="InvCode" InvCode="U1K" RatePlanCodeType="RatePlanCode" RatePlanCode="EXL" RateTier="8" IsRoom="1" Override="1"/><LengthsOfStay ArrivalDateBased="1" FixedPatternLength="1"></LengthsOfStay></AvailStatusMessage>
  <AvailStatusMessage><StatusApplicationControl Start="2014-04-27" End="2014-05-21" Sun="1" Mon="1" Tue="1" Weds="1" Thur="1" Fri="1" Sat="1" InvCodeApplication="InvCode" InvCode="U1K" RatePlanCodeType="RatePlanCode" RatePlanCode="EXL" RateTier="8" IsRoom="1" Override="1"/><LengthsOfStay ArrivalDateBased="1"
```

I have  tag , which contains field with **StatusApplicationControl Start** value . I want to get all such AvailStatusMessage tags which have StatusApplicationControl  start value as "2014-04-27".

Please assist me of getting this done using perl or shell script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example XML code, the `AvailStatusMessage` tag seems to be empty? So for this line you would like to get an empty string?

Comment: <AvailStatusMessage><StatusApplicationControl Start="2014-04-27" End="2014-05-21" Sun="1" Mon="1" Tue="1" Weds="1" Thur="1" Fri="1" Sat="1" InvCodeApplication="InvCode" InvCode="U1K" RatePlanCodeType="RatePlanCode" RatePlanCode="EXL" RateTier="8" IsRoom="1" Override="1"/><LengthsOfStay ArrivalDateBased="1" FixedPatternLength="1"></LengthsOfStay></AvailStatusMessage>

Comment: This is how availstatusmessage tag looks like(I have pasted this in my above comment) , single line contain multiple such tags in it.

Comment: Ok.. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.12;
use File::Slurp;

my $txt=read_file('file');

while ($txt=~m{<AvailStatusMessage>(.*?)</AvailStatusMessage>}gms) {
    my $atxt=$1;
    if ($atxt=~m{<StatusApplicationControl (.*?)/>}ms) {
        my $tmp=$1;
        if ($tmp=~m{Start="2014-04-27"}ms) {
            say $atxt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hakon, This might not work .. as i have text file containing text as well as xml messages . It is not a complete xml file

Comment: Ok, could you paste your file at pastebin.com, and I will have a look at it?

Comment: This is the errror i am getting ,"you seem to have used the parse method on a filename (*XML::Parser::FILE), you probably want parsefile instead at"

Comment: @RohitPant I have updated my answer. Could you check if it looks better now?

Comment: @RohitPant: It's a SOAP message. It would have helped a lot if you had said, "this is a SOAP message".

Comment: Yes , it worked for me . Really thnanks Hakon for yuour quick help.